# Strange ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting a very strange error when running a spec:

```
Failure/Error: entity = Factory.create(:entity, :name => "Test Entity", :creator => user)
 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
   ::User(#97318850) expected, got User(#92770800)
```

This is the code that results in the above error. Factory is a factory_girl factory.

```
  user = Factory(:user, :username => "kai", :email => "xxx@yyy.com", :password => "testing")
  entity = Factory.create(:entity, :name => "Test Entity", :creator => user)
```

When I use `:creator => User.first` then everything works as expected. I printed out `User.first` and `user`, but see no difference.

Any suggestions what the heck is wrong here?

### Update

I also got this error when running this simple request spec

```
describe "Entities" do
  it "should succeed" do
    entity = Factory.create(:entity, :name => "Test Entity 1")
    visit root_path
  end

  it "should also succeed" do
    entity = Factory.create(:entity, :name => "Test Entity 2")
    property = Factory.create(:property, :entity => entity)
  end
end
```

This time I get

```
Failure/Error: property = Factory.create(:property, :entity => entity)
 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
   Entity(#103620190) expected, got Entity(#96047070)
```

when I delete `visit root_path` everything works fine (also when running each spec on its own). It just seems to be a problem for request specs. The other specs (model, controller) seems to run fine. I use Capybara 1.0.0.beta1 and RSpec 2.5.

What does this number behind the class name mean?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is an error that occurs when two different versions of the model have been loaded. I used to hit it in an older version of Rails 3, since the development environment's model reloader was slightly glitched. The numbers after the class name refer to different versions of the class.

It stands to reason that this sort of error might come up in development mode, but it shouldn't in test mode, because, by default, classes are cached. See the `config/environments/test.rb` file to ensure that `cache_classes` is set to true.

Also check that you're on the latest version of Rails, 3.0.7. This may be a bug that has since been fixed. While we're at it, check that you're on factory_girl 1.3.3. When using the API totally correctly, which I think you're doing, the only possibilities left are that something is misconfigured or that it's a bug in someone else's code.

Comment: Indeed, I had `cache_classes` set to false (cause of some older issues with spork ... which in the meantime doesn't seem to be problems anymore). Everything runs fine now. Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: +1 - Thanks! This helped me as well! Been wondering what the heck it was!

Comment: I also see this sometimes when I'm running spork with cache_classes set to false so that I can run rspec quickly... I haven't found a way around it besides running the specs without spork.

Comment: Working with a backbone app on front-end (and never restarting the server) I ended up with this error, solved with a server restart as well, thanks!

Comment: This could also be related to spring, in my case `spring stop` and restarting and the test suite made the trick.

Comment: I had the same problem in the console after using `reload!`. Exiting and starting the console solved the problem. So `reload!` also has some problems with class-caching. (Using rails 4)

Answer (score 5):

Rather than disable class caching, which can be aggravating while in development, the problem might disappear if you get your object fresh before using it. In my case I was loading an object from an association:

```
desired_object = foo.bar
```

Finding the item instead removed the problem and didn't require caching classes.

```
desired_object = Bar.find(foo.bar_id)
```

I know it isn't ideal, but perhaps this will help someone find out just why it is happening at all.

Comment: I hacked around this by calling `.reload` on the object after the association, as in `foo.bar.reload`

Answer (score 1):

For the combination of Rails + Spring + factory_girl this is fixed since version v4.4.1 of factory_girl_rails (Feb 2014) see https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/pull/121

Answer (score 0):

Similar error might occur if you are using *Spring* or any other **Rails application preloader**, make sure you restart it.

```
spring stop
spring start
# or usually bin/rails s or bin/rails c for console
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was in my factory definition where I was using additional factories to populate id fields.  I accidentally referred to an attribute that didn't exist on the table (account, instead of account_id).  See example below.

```
factory Omni::CustomerAccount do
  sequence(:display_name) {|n| "test #{n}"}
  customer_id :customer  # this is correct
  account :account  # wrong - this should say account_id :account
end
```

Hope this helps someone.